# @Valid producing error when I have some read/write access fields in my DTO

Tags: spring, rest, bean-validation

Hi,

I have the following two request to be catered by my DTO:

1. PATCH request to update values:

```
{ 
    "email": "test@xyz.com",  
    "address" : "Xyz street, 4th cross, first main", 
    "city" : "Bangalore",
    "state" : "Karnataka",
    "pinCode": 560078,
    "creditDebitLimit": 5000.00,
    "amountPref":"###,###",
    "datePref": "mm/dd/yy",
    "userId":  "user_Id"
    }
```

2. GET request to view values:

```
{
    "custId":12345
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName" : "Test" ,
    "aadharId" : "704123432122",
    "email": "test@xyz.com",  
    "address" : "Xyz street, 4th cross, first main", 
    "city" : "Bangalore",
    "state" : "Karnataka",
    "pinCode": 560078,
    "creditDebitLimit":5000.00
    "amountPref":lakhs"
    "datePref":"mm/dd/yy"
}
```

The DTO class:

```
public class UpdateCustomerDTO implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty(value="cust",access=Access.READ_ONLY)
    private int custId;

    @JsonProperty(value="firstName",access=Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty(value="lastName",access=Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String lastName;

    @JsonProperty(value="aadharId",access=Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String aadharId;

    @NotBlank(message="updatecustomer.email.mandatory")
    @Email(message="updatecustomer.email.valid")
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String emailId;

    @NotBlank(message="updatecustomer.address.mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("address")
    private String address;

    @NotBlank(message="updatecustomer.city.mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("city")
    private String city;

    @NotBlank(message="updatecustomer.state.mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("state")
    private String state;

    @NotBlank(message="updatecustomer.pincode.mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("pinCode")
    private String pincode;

    @NotBlank(message="updatecustomer.creditnotification.size")
    @Digits(integer=8,fraction=4,message="newcustomer.creditnotification.size")
    @JsonProperty("creditDebitLimit")
    private BigDecimal crDbNotifLimit;

    @NotBlank(message="updatecustomer.amountPref.mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("amountPref")
    private String amountPref;

    @NotBlank(message = "updatecustomer.datePref.mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("datePref")
    private String datePref;

    @NotBlank(message = "updatecustomer.lastUpdatedId.mandatory")
    @JsonProperty(value="userId",access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String lstUpdtId;

}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{custId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public UpdateCustomerDTO viewProfile(@PathVariable int custId){
    UpdateCustomerDTO customerDTO = customerService.viewCustomerProfile(custId);
    if(customerDTO != null){

        return customerDTO;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value="/customers/{custId}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public boolean updateProfile(@Valid @RequestBody UpdateCustomerDTO updateCustomerDTO,@PathVariable int custId){
    return customerService.updateCustomerProfile(updateCustomerDTO,custId);
}
```

The GET part is working as expected but the PATCH request is throwing error:

```
{
  "errorCode": 500,
  "errorMsg": "An unknown error occured."
}
```

> But when I remove the @Valid annotation from the PATCH controller
>   everything works fine but no validation is possible then.

Comment: Error 500 means something happened with your code. Please find the stacktrace and add it to the question

Comment: I am getting nothing in the console and also I tried adding a print statement as the first line of the controller but even that was not printed.

Comment: Getting nothing in console could be fixed to out error. Check logs, check log levels

Comment: And removing Valid annotation made everything work so I think it is @Valid which is throwing this error

Comment: Thanks got the answer from logs. It seems @NotBlank does not support BigDecimal

Comment: So it's enough to remove one check (or replace with own implementation) and keep `@Valid`

Comment: Yes, replacing `@NotBlank` with `@NotNull` does the trick.